# MATLAB Yahoo data feed error

Tags: matlab, yahoo, trading, datafeed, commodity

I'm trying to use Yahoo API in MATLAB R2015a to retrieve historical data (prices) for commodities. I can get the price for current date, but not for a historical date range. So for example Last price for CK15.CBT Corn May 15:

```
clear
clc
c = yahoo;
a = fetch(c,'CK15.CBT','Last');
disp (a);

d = fetch(c,'CK15.CBT','Last','02/02/15','02/05/15');
disp (d);
```

Displaying "a" works ok, but "d" returns the following error messages:

```
Error using yahoo/fetch>isdatafield (line 543)
Current data field specified but historical data requested.

Error in yahoo/fetch (line 74)
  elseif isdatafield(varargin{1},numinputs)

Error in Untitled (line 7)
d = fetch(c,'CK15.CBT','Last','02/02/15','02/05/15');
```

Could you please help me how to work with yahoo API in MATLAB to get commodities prices for specified time range? Or do you have a suggestion for any other way how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the Datafeed toolbox so I cannot check, but you probably don't want to invoke the parameter `'Last'` when you request a range of values.

```
d = fetch(c,'CK15.CBT','02/02/15','02/05/15');
```

should work better.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that is not the problem. I think I found the problem now - it is the fact that it's a commodity. Datafeed is capable of getting data in a specified range for stocks, but not for commodities - for those only the last values, not historical. Would anyone know any other API to use to get the historical data for commodities?